# Post to php with angular doesn't return data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-http

i'm trying to post something to server and return so data to my app with angular. This is my server code.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");

// database
require("db_config.php");
//$_POST['city'] = 42;

$query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE city = :city GROUP BY category";
$query_params = array(':city' => $_POST['city']);

    try {

        $stmtOdgovor = $conn->prepare($query);
        $resultOdgovor = $stmtOdgovor->execute($query_params);

    } catch(PDOException $ex){
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database error";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $rowsOdgovor = $stmtOdgovor->fetchAll();

    if ($rowsOdgovor){

        $responseOdgovor = array();
        foreach ($rowsOdgovor as $rowOdgovor) {
            $postOdgovor["category"] = $rowOdgovor["category"];
            array_push($responseOdgovor, $postOdgovor);
        }
        echo json_encode($responseOdgovor);

    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No locations available";

    }
```

And this is my client code :

```
$http({

        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://glutenfree.hr/rest/all_cities.php',

        dataType:'json',
        data:{'city':$stateParams.cityId},
        headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert();
        //response.data ti je to
        console.log(response); 

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response); 
    });
```

When i write thos paramether in php, it works, but when i'm posting it with angular it does'nt. Can anybody explain what is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Why do you not outputting anything if `$rowsOdgovor` equals to `false`?

Comment: no errors on client side...just returning this $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database error";

Comment: are you sure `$stateParams.cityId` has the value that you want to post to the server?

Comment: Why is the content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` but the `dataType` json? This code looks like it was pasted from multiple sources randomly.

Comment: pls post your code in html

Comment: i solved. For angular post this is need in php: 
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    @$email = $request->email;
    @$pass = $request->pass;
    echo $email;